# How to use TidyQuant in R in an efficient way

Tags: r, tidyquant

I would like to use TidyQuant to produce several performance statistics from a dataframe of symbol returns. I have worked out that I can do the following to get the max and average drawdowns for each symbol:

```
maxDD <- monthlyReturns %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  tq_performance(
    Ra = Ra, 
    Rb = NULL, 
    performance_fun = maxDrawdown
  )

  avgDD <- monthlyReturns %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  tq_performance(
    Ra = Ra, 
    Rb = NULL, 
    performance_fun = AverageDrawdown
  )
```

It strikes me that calling these 2 functions separately is very inefficient.  Surely the function has to generate all drawdowns separately for each call before being able to calculate the max and the average.

Is there a way to make this more efficient by calling tq_performance once and giving it a list of similar sub functions so the required underlying data (drawdowns) only has to be computed once?